# In what form of ELF is a core dump file?

Tags: core-dump, elf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format mentions core dumps.

In what form of ELF is a core dump file?  Relocatable, executable, or shared?

[CSAPP](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) says

> 7.3 Object Files
>
> Object ﬁles come in three forms:
>
> Relocatable object ﬁle. Contains binary code and data in a form that
> can be combined with other relocatable object ﬁles at compile time to
> create an executable object ﬁle.
>
> Executable object ﬁle. Contains binary code and data in a form that
> can be copied directly into memory and executed.
>
> Shared object ﬁle. A special type of relocatable object ﬁle that can
> be loaded into memory and linked dynamically, at either load time or
> run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those three.

The type of the ELF file is determined by the e-type

```
Name      Value    Meaning
ET_NONE   0        No file type
ET_REL    1        Relocatable file
ET_EXEC   2        Executable file
ET_DYN    3        Shared object file
ET_CORE   4        Core file
ET_LOOS   0xfe00   Operating system-specific
ET_HIOS   0xfeff   Operating system-specific
ET_LOPROC 0xff00   Processor-specific
ET_HIPROC 0xffff   Processor-specific
```

And a core dump is ET_CORE.